# Why am I getting a TypeError: pandas._libs.missing.isnaobj() when trying to create a df with only column names on Python? Pandas 1.4.0 related

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, debugging, typeerror

I recently updated my pandas version to `1.4.0`, I open `Python 3.9.6` to test it out.

I simply wanted to create a df with only column names using the following code

```
import pandas as pd

#column names
column_names = ["Time", "Currency", "Volatility expected", "Event", "Actual", "Forecast", "Previous"]

#create a dataframe including the column names
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=column_names)
```

This code was built based on the explanation of [this guide](https://www.statology.org/pandas-create-dataframe-with-column-names/).

However, after running the code above, I ended up getting this error:

> TypeError: pandas._libs.missing.isnaobj() takes no keyword arguments

I can't figure out where's the problem in the syntax, so I came here to ask and learn about it.

Comment: Your code works perfectly for me. Pandas 1.4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works perfectly for me. Pandas 1.4.1 and Python 3.9.7

`pandas._libs.missing` refer to a `cython` module. Try to upgrade `numpy` and (not mandatory) install `cython` package:

```
[...]$ pip install -U numpy

[...]$ pip install cython
```

Comment: Now it works, it seems however `Spyder` is not letting me see the `df` that was created, it throws `Spyder was unable to retrieve the value of this variable from the console`

Comment: It seems that my issue will be solved at the end of this month: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/17342. Meaning that I had to downgrade my Pandas version to `1.3.5` using `pip install -Iv --user pandas==1.3.5` on `cmd`, and `conda install pandas==1.3.5` on my `miniconda3` environment